# How can I do a nested sort on NSManagedObjects iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nssortdescriptor

Does anyone know how to do a nested sort (not sure if that's the best term for it) using NSSortDescriptors?

I'm using NSSortDescriptors to fetch NSManagedObjects.

I have a NSManagedObject called Conversation that has a one-to-many relationship to Messages. Each Conversation has a NSSet of Messages.

Each Message has a timeReceived Date property. I'm trying to sort my Conversations by their respective latest Message's timeReceiveds

To restate: I'm trying to find the Message with the last timeReceived in each Conversation, then sort the Conversations by their respective latest Messages. Messages and Conversations are NSManagedObjects.

The Key string nature of these descriptors has made it really hard for me to figure out.

I saw something on SO that suggested something like:
NSSortDescriptor * sortByDate = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"messages.@min.timeReceived" ascending:NO];

But I just get a crash:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Keypath containing KVC aggregate where there shouldn't be one; failed to handle messages.@max.timeReceived'
```

Have any of you done something like this before?

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *) fetchSortedConversations
{
    NSSortDescriptor *sortByDate = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"latestMessage.timeReceived" ascending:NO];

    // I implemented a workaround where I set a latestMessage for each Conversation somewhere else, but I'd like to be able to sort the Conversations without having to manually manage the latest message.

    NSArray * sortDescriptors = @[sortByDate];

    NSFetchedResultsController * conversations = [self.coreDataManager fetchEntitiesWithName: NSStringFromClass([Conversation class]) sortDescriptors:sortDescriptors sectionNameKeyPath:nil predicate:nil];


    return conversations;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would assume the problem you're facing can't be solved with `NSFetchedResultsController` as currently formulated, because it can't really be solved neatly in SQL. So `NSFetchRequest` probably just declines to do it, and that bubbles upward.

The easiest solution would be to implement `- willSave` on the managed object subclass you've got for `Conversation` and in that find `@max.timeReceived` and store it to a property directly in `Conversation`. Then tell your fetched results controller to sort on that.

Comment: so I'm not sure how core data structures the data, but I was imagining it like:

messages table
message
timereceived
conversation

in which case, couldn't i query out what i'm looking for something like this?

select conversation, message_time  from
/// finds the message with the lowest time received for each conversation
(
select conversation, min(timeReceived) as message_time from messages group by conversation
)

order by message_time DESC;

or is this what you meant by not solved neatly? :) is this kind of query too complex for nsfetchrequest? maybe i'm totally off.

Comment: That would surely work for querying the messages table, not the conversations table? `NSFetchRequest` in this case needs an `order by` for the conversations table since it's fetching conversation — and bear in mind that Core Data fetches one entity at a time. So no joins.

Comment: interesting. i just put the latestMessage logic into willSave in a Conversation category. seems reasonably reasonable. thanks, tommy!